# Regularity under set difference

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

Let L be a regular language.
Then $\Sigma^{*} \backslash L^{*} = (\Sigma^{*} \backslash L)^{*}$

How do I prove it is wrong?

Comment: You can't prove it, since it's wrong.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus and how do I prove it wrong?

Comment: You find a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance, take $\Sigma=\{a,b\}$ and $L=\{a\}$.

Then, $L^*=\{\epsilon,a,aa,\ldots\}$ and $\Sigma^*\setminus L^*$ comprises any word except those made by only $a$s. In other terms, those words containing at least one $b$.

Instead $(\Sigma^*\setminus L)$ comprises any words except $a$ (this includes $aa$, for instance). So, $(\Sigma^*\setminus L)^*$ comprises all concatenations of words which are not $a$. Well, this is the same set of words: all the words except $a$.

Concluding, it is easy to see that $aa$ belongs to the latter set but not the first one.

---

Not only we can find a counterexample, but we can even prove that the equation is false whatever $L$ is! Indeed, the empty word $\epsilon \in (\Sigma^*\setminus L)^* \setminus (\Sigma^*\setminus L^*)$ is a wtiness to their difference.